# docx4j: help converting docx to PDF

Tags: pdf, docx, docx4j

My goal is to take an existing .docx file and convert it, from a Linux command-line, to PDF using docx4j (http://www.docx4java.orghttp://www.docx4java.org). The "getting started" guide (http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html) refers to a samples directory that isn't actually included in the latest (2.8.1) package. Regardless, I located the samples directory in their SVN browser, created a 'samples/' subdirectory in my docx4j folder containing all the .jar files, and downloaded the CreatePdf.java file into the samples directory. Then I tried running:

```
java -cp docx4j-2.8.1.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar org.docx4j.samples.CreatePdf my-file.docx
```

And I get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class samples.org.docx4j.samples.CreatePdf
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The samples are included in 2.8.1. Nothing has changed there, except the name of the sample, which is now **ConvertOutPDF**

Please try that instead.

btw, the SVN repository has been superseded since May.  See [docx4j-from-github-in-eclipse](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/docx4j-from-github-in-eclipse/)

Comment: I just unpacked the 2.8.1 zip and all it contains is jar files. No subdirectories. No sample .java files.

Comment: You can get the source from GitHub, or from http://search.maven.org (search for docx4j)

Comment: I feel this answer is valuable, but it does not answer the question.